# VisibilityOfElementLocated Vs presenceOfElementLocated

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

Consider this:

```
val element = ...
String str = element.getAttribute("innerHTML")
```

So in case i only wants to get this `value` is it enough to use `presenceOfElementLocated()` instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated()` ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use both [`presenceOfElementLocated`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) or [`visibilityOfElementLocated`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) to get the `value`.

But for the performance perspective, I would guess that [`presenceOfElementLocated`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) will be slightly faster because it's just check that an **element is present on the DOM of a page**. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible. while the [`visibilityOfElementLocated`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) has to check that an **element is present on the DOM of a page and visible**. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

**So according to your case use of [`presenceOfElementLocated`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) will be enough.**

you can consider the following point to choose appropriate method depending on your use case.

- use [`presenceOfElementLocated`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) when you don't care whether if element
  visible or not, you just need to know if it's on the page.
- use [`visibilityOfElementLocated`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) when you need to find element which
  should be also visible.

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 3):

### presenceOfElementLocated()

[`presenceOfElementLocated()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By)) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> presenceOfElementLocated​(By locator)

Parameters:
locator - used to find the element
Returns:
the WebElement once it is located
```

---

### visibilityOfElementLocated()

[`visibilityOfElementLocated()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By)) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> visibilityOfElementLocated​(By locator)

Parameters:
locator - used to find the element
Returns:
the WebElement once it is located and visible
```

---

### This usecase

To get the value of the *`innerHTML`* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) ideally the element needs to be **visible** instead of just being **present**. So you have to use **`visibilityOfElementLocated()`**.

Your effective [java](/questions/tagged/java) based code block will be:

- Using `visibilityOfElementLocated()`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("elementCssSelector")));
  System.out.println(element.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```
- In a single line:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("elementCssSelector"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```

---

Your effective [python](/questions/tagged/python) based code block will be:

- Using `visibility_of_element_located()`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css_selector")))
  print(element.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- In a single line:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css_selector")))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

---

Your effective [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) based code block will be:

- Using `ElementIsVisible()`:

  ```
  var element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("ElementCssSelector")));
  Console.WriteLine(element.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```
- In a single line:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("ElementCssSelector"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get the value `presenceOfElementLocated` is enough to extract the value.

`visibilityOfElementLocated` is for testing purposes. To see what happens to an element when you interact with it somehow for example.