# Waiting for a table to load completely using selenium Webdriver with java

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, selenium

Is there a way to wait for a table to load completely using selenium with java?
In my case it looks like the tables loaded using ajax and/or jquery.
So far the only possible solution i could find it so put a simply timeout/pause in a milliseconds.
I'm looking for more advanced solution and not hard-coded one.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks!

Comment: Is there any loading image appear until table fully loaded???

Comment: @palaѕн I've added what i tried to do so far.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur No ,images are not loaded at all.

Comment: after the driver try to initialize driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: @LeonBarkan There is a timeout, it is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

Selenium provides [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) with [`ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) to wait for element visible on the [`DOM`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). You should try as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By...));
```

**Note** :- Here you can provide [`By`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) locator as [`.id()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#id-java.lang.String-),[`.className()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#className-java.lang.String-), [`.xpath()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#xpath-java.lang.String-), [`.cssSelector()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#cssSelector-java.lang.String-) etc.. of your table element. It will wait for `30` seconds to check visibilty of your table on the [`DOM`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

It will throw [`TimeoutException`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TimeoutException.html) exception if element will not be visible within `30 seconds`.

For eg :- if you want to check visibility of your table with the `id`, you just run as `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("your table id")));`

You can increase or decrease the timeout also..

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: Thank you , i will try this solution. can you please just exaplin what is DOM? also what the number 30 means? is it like milliseconds/seconds of timeout for the element to be visible ? and if it won't it will throw exception?Also what is the usage of el afterwards? just i just run wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By...)); ?  Thanks.

Comment: @ZvikaNadav The Document Object Model (DOM) is a programming API for HTML and XML documents. It defines the logical structure of documents and the way a document is accessed and manipulated

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will try it and see if tests are not failing anymore, hopefully :) I will let you.

Comment: @ZvikaNadav `el` is the reference variable of the `WebElement` object where you can perform certain action like `el.click()` etc...

Comment: @ZvikaNadav 30 is the time out limit in second.. you can increase or decrease it also..

Comment: @ZvikaNadav yes it will throw `TimeoutException` if element will not be visible within 30 seconds

Comment: You need to run like as `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("table id")));`...if you want to locate it with the id of the table

Comment: Thank you for the information . At the moment your solution solves the issue of mine, do yo know exactly what is the actual process behind the screen of the ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated ? Could you explain about it abit more? Thanks

Comment: @ZvikaNadav `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated`  checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0. for more details have a look http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/2.32.0/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29

Comment: This is great, thank you for the information and the link, very useful. Do you have any other websites like so that i can research selenium methods/functionalities ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ZvikaNadav you are always welcome..I provided every points with the link in the answer.. you can click to know about on every points...keep learning...:)

Comment: Thanks, very appreciated.

Comment: Hey, sadly i tried to run other test the issue still appears, if i simply run without any timeout/breakpoint, the test fails because the table is not fully loaded. any other idea maybe?

Comment: @ZvikaNadav Why are you not using `WebDriverWait` here???..Could you share your code that have you tried so far??

Comment: I am using a WD wait with a properties timeout set. it seems like the selenium sees the page loads and trying to do w/e command to get table data but it fails because it did not load fully.

Comment: @ZvikaNadav make sure your locator to locate table is correct Then increase the timeout...:)

Comment: I made sure it is under <table id='TABLE_NAME'...> , as i said the issue is where selenium is already executing the next command where the page is loaded but the table is not fully loaded(used by ajax)

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, EnvironmentUtils.getPageLoadTimeout().intValue());        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*/table[@id='" + tableID + "']/tbody"))); That is the code i'm running at the moment for my table methods, i changed it to presenseOfElementLocated to try it out at the moment. I can't seem to find the different between visibilityOfElementLocated and presenseOfElementLocated according to the website you gave.

Comment: @ZvikaNadav Is there timeout exception occurs when you tried this code???

Comment: Is `EnvironmentUtils.getPageLoadTimeout().intValue()` returns enough timeout for loading your table or not??

Comment: Have a look for the difference between visibilityOfElementLocated and presenseOfElementLocated..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038920/visibilityofelementlocated-vs-presenceofelementlocated/38046692#38046692

Comment: the timeout is not the issue, the issue that after the click command i verify that the table is not empty of rows but it does throw exception there, the timeout is good. thanks for sharing  the answer between the methods. Also, i am sorry but i can not share the website/ fully html code. Do you mind telling me what you are looking in the html code? Also i just wanted to let you know that i asked another question here, i am trying now to use waitUntil jquery/animation/ajax is completed, i hope that i do not miss any statements there

Comment: @ZvikaNadav i think no need to ask another question provided answer is correct to solve your problem... i want HTML for looking a best locator to wait until complete... i just want to know which element be present at last after jquery/animation/ajax is completed.. thats why locator could wait for that element until present...

Comment: I tried to use the Id of the table but it does not help.

Comment: @ZvikaNadav it is hard to say which locator is best and which condition is best without seeing any live example... thanks

Comment: I do not understand, if I expect the table will show and load with details and the locator is not the Id of the table what else then?

Comment: @ZvikaNadav I have already provided in the answer.. you can also use other locator like as `By.name()`,`By.className()`, `By.xpath()`, .`By.cssSelector()` etc instead of id...

Comment: I have tried other locator attributes for my case, it does not the case sadly. Thanks.

Comment: @ZvikaNadav I'm sorry but I couldn't provide you exact solution without seeing your table that how it works and when it load...thanks

Comment: @ZvikaNadav Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201425/wait-for-an-ajax-call-to-complete-with-selenium-2-web-driver...may be it helps

Comment: Hey , if you go to [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333904/selenium-webdriver-wait-for-page-to-completely-load-in-javajavascriptajax-jq/38337184#38337184 you can see my method that i am currently using, it is the same as the guys in the link you provided are suggesting. Thanks