# Selenium Webdriver - wait for page to completely load in Java&JavaScript(ajax/jquery/animation etc.)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, selenium

I am trying to build a better method for waiting for a page to load after each click.
At the moment what i have used is this:

```
    public boolean waitForJSandJQueryToLoad() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, EnvironmentUtils.getPageLoadTimeout().intValue());
    // wait for jQuery to load
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                if (!((Boolean) callJS("return (window.jQuery != null) && (jQuery.active === 0);"))) {
                    log.info("JQUERY.ACTIVE IS WORKING AT THE MOMENT! jQuery.active= " + callJS("return jQuery.active"));
                }
                return (Boolean) callJS("return (window.jQuery != null) && (jQuery.active === 0);");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // no jQuery present
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
    // wait for Javascript to load
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            if (!callJS("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete")) {
                log.info("document.readyState is not complete at the moment! status is->" + callJS("return document.readyState").toString());
            }
            return callJS("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
        }
    };

    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> animationLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            if (!callJS("return $(\":animated\").length").toString().equals("0")) {
                log.info("Animation is currently executing on-page. value ->" + callJS("return $(\":animated\").length").toString());
            }
            return callJS("return $(\":animated\").length").toString().equals("0");
        }
    };

    return wait.until(jQueryLoad) && wait.until(jsLoad) && wait.until(animationLoad);
}
```

in some cases my tests still fails after clicking on some button and waiting for a table to load afterwards but when I ran countRowsInTable method(which count rows in a table by selenium command) it brings out zero while the actual visual is not zero at all,  the command of count rows is working properly, here's the code if you want to check it:

```
public int countDisplayedRowsInTable(String tableId) {
    waitForJSandJQueryToLoad();
    int count = 0;
    List<WebElement> rows = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='" + tableId + "']/tbody/tr"));
    for (WebElement row : rows) {
        if (row.isDisplayed())
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I am pretty sure that i covered anything with my waitForJSandJQueryToLoad method, i hope that you may give me additional statement that maybe i missed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you  provide the link to the application or any specific framework of the application?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not allowed. Can you please let me know what you are looking for?

Comment: Instead of checking all those conditions pinpoint what happens after each click..like if any loader icon is running or some text is being displayed.If so wait for that element to be visible/invisible.. And how do we check if your function is  working or not.It may work for some sites but not for others or your application..You can atleast tell the framwork in which the application is built[angular-js,ext-js..)

Comment: I've tried already to use element visible , it does not help because the element is visible but it needs to be loaded when searching for example.

Comment: Is the table jquery-datatable or jtable or any other table framwork

Comment: in some cases when searching for a data and loading the table jQuery.active is 1, so i guess it is jquery data-table, the issue is that in some cases where the test fails the jQuery.active zero but the table is not fully loaded yet (count displayed rows returns zero.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define an explicit wait that waits for a certain condition to occur before moving on in the code.

```
    public int countDisplayedRowsInTable(String tableId) {
        String e = "//table[@id='" + tableId + "']";

        // Wait for the table to load
        WebElement table = (new WebDriverWait(driver, intCustomWait))
          .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(e));

        // Get all the rows from within the table
        List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.xpath("./tbody/tr"));
        if(rows.size() > 0)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (WebElement row : rows) {
                if (row.isDisplayed())
                count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
        else return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i have tried to see if ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable By.id of the table but it seems to not work. according to the html code its loaded by ajax/jquery. but again, i have tried to use my waitForJSandJQueryToLoad, maybe i do need to combine both of this methods in order to make it work.

Comment: Hey, i just tried your method and it is not working because in a case where the table is empty of rows but is still display,  Timed out after Xseconds waiting for element to be clickable. elementToBeClickable seems to not solve the issue at the moment, thanks.