# Selenium: different behaviour debugging versus running. Wrong WebDriverWait?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Following code runs as expected if manually stepped in debug while it misbehaves if just run.

Aside from some initial code to reach the search page, I am then requesting a value which I know does not exist ("ZQZZQ") and thus the code should branch into the last else statement.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    "/Users/bob/Documents/work/AIFA/scraper/scrape_gu/chromedriver"
)

# navigate through the initial agreement screens
driver.get("https://farmaci.agenziafarmaco.gov.it/bancadatifarmaci/cerca-farmaco")
readunderstood = driver.find_element_by_id("conf")
readunderstood.click()
accept = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/button"))
)
accept.click()
# end of the initial agreement screens and general preparation
##############################################################

string_to_search = "ZQZZQ"  # we can safely assume this does not exist

find_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("search")
find_textbox.clear()  # after the first search the old value will still be there
find_textbox.send_keys(string_to_search)
find_textbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# check if any results found
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "noresultsfound"))
)
# if we did retrieve something we don't have an error message
if element.text != "Nessun risultato trovato":
    # first we have to find out the total number of retrieved pages
    print(f"Digram {string_to_search} found!")
else:
    print(f"Digram {string_to_search} not found. Need to close modal window!")
    # click on ok of name not found modal dialog
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/button"))
    ).click()
    print("Modal window hopefully closed")
```

When I run it at full speed though I find it goes into the "if" branch, printing "Digram ZQZZQ found!" which is wrong.

Is the WebDriverWait call wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the "presence_of_element_located" method to "visibility_of_element_located".

**Old Code:**

```
# check if any results found
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "noresultsfound"))
```

**Change:**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='noresultsfound']"))
)
```

**Output**:

```
Digram ZQZZQ not found. Need to close modal window!
Modal window hopefully closed
```

**VisibilityOfElementLocated Vs presenceOfElementLocated:**

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038920/visibilityofelementlocated-vs-presenceofelementlocated#:~:text=while%20the%20visibilityOfElementLocated%20has%20to,of%20presenceOfElementLocated%20will%20be%20enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038920/visibilityofelementlocated-vs-presenceofelementlocated#:%7E:text=while%20the%20visibilityOfElementLocated%20has%20to,of%20presenceOfElementLocated%20will%20be%20enough).

Comment: Thank a lot. Works and also am learning new things :)