# Selenium Python Trying to Better Understand WebDriverWait and Splash/Transition Screens

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm coding for a website that uses the transition screen below in between each data screen, including when you first connect to the site.

[image]

So this screen appears before the initial login screen.  My code to sign into the page is:

```
try:
    #username
    user_val = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))
    user_val.send_keys(usr)

    #password 
    pwd_val = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
    pwd_val.send_keys(pwd)
    pwd_val.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
except:
    logger.info("Step 1: Login prompt not found - could not log into Veritas.")
```

[image]

Because of the transition screen it's blowing past this code and hitting the exception.  I've been able to correct the problem by putting time.sleep(3) as the first line of code, but I would have thought that using WebDriverWait(browser, 10)...would have searched for this node for 10 seconds before giving up on it.  Is that not happening because it's looking for this element on the transition screen? And if that's the case, is there a better way to delay my code until the transition screen has passed? I hate using the time.sleep method but it's the only thing I could think to do.

Comment: You can try using EC.visibility_of_element_located() when waiting for your username/password inputs. Probably your inputs are present in the HTML already, but not rendered yet. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38046692/23182657) to understand the difference. In general, WebDriverWait should resolve such issues. Alternatively, you can wait for the transition screen to disappear (EC.invisibility_of_element_located() by some unique identifier). But waiting for something 'to not be present' is not really preferable in UI automation (it may appear right after the check is finished).

Comment: I had the same issue using EC.visibility_of_element_located(), but you put me on the right path!! I'm still learning selenium and forgot there are other calls, so after some research I found EC.element_to_be_clickable() and that worked!!  Thanks for taking the time to respond and help a brother out!!